# How to use timing functions with animation-play-state

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an animation that should stop on hover:

```css
.animated {
    animation-duration: 19000ms;
    animation-play-state: running; /* switches to “paused” on hover via JS */
}
```

The problem is: I don’t like the “sudden” stop effect. I want to use something like `ease-in-out` to have a smooth start/stop. Is there a way to achieve this with `animation-play-state`?
If not, what alternatives I can use?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is such a property that can do that. But you may consider getting approximate result by combining another animation. Here is an example:

Note: These values '550ms' and '30deg' are manually adjusted, maybe there's an equation to calculate one with the other value determined.

```js
function enter() {
    animated.style['animation-play-state'] = 'paused';
    animated.style.transition = 'rotate 550ms ease-out';
  animated.style.rotate = parseFloat(animated.style.rotate || '0') + 30 + 'deg';
}

function leave() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    animated.style['animation-play-state'] = 'running';
  }, 550);
    animated.style.transition = 'rotate 550ms ease-in';
  animated.style.rotate = parseFloat(animated.style.rotate || '0') + 30 + 'deg';
}
```

```css
#animated {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 100px;
  border-color: red blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: 4s spin infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animated" onmouseenter="enter()" onmouseleave="leave()"/>
```